# Get values from methods in objects that are in arraylist?

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
// add object to arraylist
customerList.add(customer);

// get objects from arraylist
customerlist.get(0);
```

But how do I get the value from a method that is inside the class like if I have a method like getCustomerName() inside and I want the name in return or perhaps I want to change or add something to a method. How do I write the call? Preciate some help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Single reference.
customerlist.get(0).getCustomerName();

// Or...
Customer c = customerlist.get(0);
c.getCustomerName();

// Or looping.
for (Customer c : customerList) {
    c.getCustomerName();
}
```

Once you have a reference to the `Customer` object you can do whatever things you normally do to customers.

Comment: Aha! That easy! So if I want to set some information I can just call the method like customerlist.get(0).setCustomerName("Sandra"); ??

Comment: @3D-kreativ Yep :) Although for something like that, it seems like it would be better to do all that work on the customer before adding it to the list, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hmmm, well I'm doing a task that is like a simple bank system where you create objects like Customers and SavingsAccount. And my idea was to store all Customer objects in one arraylist and all SavingsAccount objects in one arraylist. It must be possible to change the balance and name in the objects, thats why I wondered how to add new values to the objects in the arraylist. I'm new to this, so it's a little bit confusing, but I'm learning.

Comment: @3D-kreativ, Perhaps write a singleton manager class that's responsible for adding/retrieving accounts?

Comment: @3D-kreativ Hmm. To me it seems like a `Customer` should have a collection of accounts, or a single account. Things get interesting once you realize that an account could be associated with multiple customers.

Comment: I also have a arraylist inside the Customer object to store the custumers all accounts. Could you be kind to explain the last part some more about "an account could be associated with multiple customers." My way is perhaps not the best?

Comment: Thanks Крысa, how would a "singleton manager class" look and work?

Comment: @3D-kreativ In "real life", an account can have multiple holders, like a husband and wife might have a join account. So there *is* a "master list" of accounts (like a map keyed on account number), and the two customers would each have a reference to the same account. Also in real life you have to deal with synchronization--it just depends on how far you want to take it.

Comment: OK, in my task I only need to handle several accounts for one customer. My "bank" doesn't allow accounts with several owners, but it's true "in real life" an account can have several users. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can implement that using Map

as you have to locate some certain object using the id

map.get(id).setBalance(map.get(id).getBalance() + 100000);